# Testing code immediately invoked in a script

Tags: unit-testing, lua, lua-busted

I'm currently writing unit tests for a lua mod library using Busted. The file in question defines a module with some functions, then calls one of those functions at the bottom to initialize itself.

The problem I'm finding is that Busted appears to be evaluating the required-in file twice.

**Test**

```
it('does a thing', function()
    -- Some setup, replacing globals etc
    require('items')
    assert.are_equal(2, #Items._registry)
end)
```

**Module**

```
Items = { _registry = {} }
function Items.do_some_stuff() end
function some_util_func() end
function load_registry()
  print(debug.traceback())
  for i, itm in pairs(Items.do_some_stuff()) do
    Items._registry[i] = itm
  end
end

load_registry()
```

As you can see, although I've simplified the code and names, the structure is nothing out of the blue (as I understand.)

The test will always fail, because `#Items._registry` is always 0 (and dumping to the console verifies that). I tried printing inside the method and found it printed twice; then I tried using `debug.traceback` at the top of that unction and found the below. As you can see, the stack traceback is printing twice, suggesting the code is being evaluated twice.

**Is this something anybody else has come across?** Am I structuring my test wrong for this scenario? Or this a bug?

---

```
stack traceback:
    items.lua:96: in function 'load_registry'
    items.lua:109: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    spec/items_pec.lua:50: in function <spec/items_spec.lua:39>
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.2/busted/core.lua:178: in function 'safe'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.2/busted/init.lua:40: in function 'executor'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.2/busted/core.lua:312: in function </usr/local/share/lua/5.2/busted/core.lua:312>
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.2/busted/core.lua:178: in function 'safe'
    ...
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.2/busted/core.lua:312: in function 'execute'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.2/busted/block.lua:155: in function 'execute'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.2/busted/init.lua:7: in function 'executor'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.2/busted/core.lua:312: in function </usr/local/share/lua/5.2/busted/core.lua:312>
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.2/busted/core.lua:178: in function 'safe'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.2/busted/core.lua:312: in function 'execute'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.2/busted/execute.lua:58: in function 'execute'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.2/busted/runner.lua:174: in function </usr/local/share/lua/5.2/busted/runner.lua:11>
    /usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks/busted/2.0.rc12-1/bin/busted:3: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
stack traceback:
    items.lua:96: in function 'load_registry'
    items.lua:109: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    spec/items_spec.lua:15: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.2/busted/core.lua:178: in function 'safe'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.2/busted/block.lua:146: in function 'execute'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.2/busted/init.lua:7: in function 'executor'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.2/busted/core.lua:312: in function </usr/local/share/lua/5.2/busted/core.lua:312>
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.2/busted/core.lua:178: in function 'safe'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.2/busted/core.lua:312: in function 'execute'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.2/busted/execute.lua:58: in function 'execute'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.2/busted/runner.lua:174: in function </usr/local/share/lua/5.2/busted/runner.lua:11>
    /usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks/busted/2.0.rc12-1/bin/busted:3: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on here as your stack trace doesn't relate to your simplified code, and we don't know what load_registry does. I'd recommend refactoring your module using the new style: http://lua-users.org/wiki/ModulesTutorial

Comment: Fair point. I've added an implementation for the `load_registry` function and edited the names in the stack trace to match up with the example.

Comment: I've tried your example locally and I only get one output, what command are you running to test, is there any other code that might be causing problems?

Comment: I'm running simply `busted -t test_in_question -o plainTerminal`, on a Win 10 machine. This happens both through the new Linux subsystem and a standard Windows install of Lua. 

The module under test imports 2 additional modules, but those 2 modules are imported ahead of time by the spec and the globals they expose are mocked, with `_G.A = { some_func }`.

The only other place this module is imported is in the tests of it functions (I've separated the tests for the its on-load behaviour to a separate spec) but by running with the `-t` flag I should be running the exact test only, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question lay in some detail I thought was extraneous but wasn't (see my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39336569/testing-code-immediately-invoked-in-a-script?noredirect=1#comment66076076_39336569)).

In particular, I separated tests for the modules on-load behaviour from the tests for its various functions. Even when running with `busted -t` to target a specific test, the imports of the module under test were being evaluated in both specs; even when the `require` call was placed in the `setup` function for the root `describe` block.

By merging the two specs I was able to work around this double-loading.